# How to know if Ho-oh or any other legend is legitimate?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

Yesterday, I placed a Zygarde on the GTS, and I asked in return for a Ho-oh.
To my surprise today, I got the Ho-oh, it was **shiny**, and it had 5ivs! (all in the good places!)

I checked to see the Ho-oh's summary, and it said

> Travelled from time and Space from Johto to get to Kalos

What does this mean? is my Ho-oh (gulp) ..not legit?

Comment: If it was cheated, it would probably have perfect IVs all over. Shiny+5IVs looks like RNG, which is totally legit (Or a very good cheat, which can't be distinguished).

Comment: What's RNG? How do you do it in XY?

Comment: RNG is short for `Random Number Generator` and refers to methods used to trick/abuse the limited predictability of the games' random number generation system in order to generate Pokémon with specific stats and characteristics. To my knowledge, the Gen 6 RNG has not yet been figured out and there is little incentive to do so because the breeding system has become so easy that it's arguably as easy to breed a perfect shiny normally as it is to RNG it. The legendaries have also been made easier to reset for good stats (they have at least 3 IVs at 31), and there are very few in the first place.

Comment: This particular Ho-Oh was definitely cheated. But it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: @HugoZink How can you tell, sir?

Comment: @Malky.Kid a Ho-Oh is a pretty rare Pokemon. I believe you can only get one per playthrough in most games. On top of that, it's also shiny (an incredibly low chance). It also has perfect IV's, *and* someone is just giving it away on the trade system. Definitely cheated. The person probably has 50 more. The stats are most likely legitimately obtainable though, so don't feel too bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to figure out is through a legitimacy checker, which can be found on the internet, but usually involves cheating to access the coding to find out.

But, for the Time and Space part, all that means is that the Pokemon was from a previous game. Probably from Heart Gold or Soul Silver via means of Poke Transfer and Poke Bank.

As long as it does not have illegal stats, abilities, types, or moves, you can use it in online competition.

EDIT: Pokemon that have traveled across space and time can be used in non-ranked online battles, but to be used on the ranked side of the battles, they need to have been caught/bred in the 6th generation games.

Comment: Legit or not, can I challenge battles with other players?

Comment: @Malky.Kid You should be able to, yes

Comment: Wait a second.. How can you get pokemon from Heartgold / Soulsilver into X & Y?

Comment: @Mkalafut gen 4 can move to gen 5 via Poketransfer, and gen 5 pokemon can be moved into Pokemonbank with Pokemon Transporter, anything in the bank can be moved into gen 6. Illegitimate pokemon are supposed to be prevented from entering Pokemon Transporter but it's possible they've been hacked directly rather than imported from hacked gen 4

Comment: @PrinnyBrocka Awesome, thanks.  I just stumbled on to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/is-it-possible-to-trade-pokemon-from-the-1st-generation-games-to-the-most-recent and it had exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If it travelled through Pokémon Bank (ie. came from Johto in this case) then it has already been through Nintendo's hack checks. With that in mind, it's either legit or good enough of a hack to not be detected.

That said, one of my friends has a Bug Bite Scizor with a Kalos-native symbol on its Summary, and another friend is probably personally responsible for the delay in Bank's release due to pointing out some major flaws in the hack checking system!

Anyway, point is, just because it's shiny and has high IVs does not mean it's hacked - it just means the person who obtained it has no life :p Okay, that was mean...