# Is there a way to trade older gen pokemon onto ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Is there a way for me to obtain my 5th gen pokemon without..
A) Using the Pokebank.
B) Trading each pokemon individually with a willing friend?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/12830/46740), there is no way to transfer a Pokémon from Gen 5 or older to Gen 6 (ORAS) without using the PokéBank, and no way to transfer it back to Gen 5 from the bank either.

Comment: Okay cheers. However I beleive you can trade x with ORAS in pps so ill try that.

Comment: Of course you can trade between XY and ORAS, they're both 6th gen games.