# Can you trade Pokemon from 7th gen (Sun/Moon) to 6th gen (XY, ORAS) and back?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-bank, pokemon-seventh-generation

Title says it all, I don't see confirmation in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/is-it-possible-to-trade-pokemon-from-the-1st-generation-games-to-the-most-recent#12830) and a cursory google search seemed to say assume no and speculate about the pokemon bank.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this image:

[image]

*Pokemon Bank* will receive an update for compatibility with Pokemon Sun/Moon in January 2017, but you will be able to trade Pokemon from 6th gen **to** 7th gen only, and not back.

As you can read in the white box:

> Pokemon not sent to Sun/Moon can continue to be used in X/Y or OR/AS.

Source from [Pokemon official site](http://www.pokemon-sunmoon.com/en-au/pokemon-bank/).

---

If you mean a direct trade, then NO.
According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLScQRF84v0) and [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-sun-pokemon-moon/How_to_Transfer_Your_Old_Pokemon_to_Sun_and_Moon):

> Pokemon Sun and Moon are not compatible with the Generation 6 series of games: Pokemon X and Y; and Pokemon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire. You won't be able to trade or battle between these games and Pokemon Sun and Moon, therefore you'll need a special app called the Pokemon Bank to transfer your Pokemon.