# Is it possible to transfer from Sun/Moon to X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-bank, pokemon-seventh-generation

My daughter has the game Sun and Moon, she just got the game X and Y, she is trying to transfer her pokemon from Sun/Moon over with the bank-transfer app but when she goes to move them over it tells her she is unable to move that character, any suggestions please?? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is not possible.

You can transfer Pokémon from X/Y/OR/AS to Pokémon Sun/Moon through the Pokébank and you can put Pokémon from Sun/Moon on the Pokébank.

Unfortunately, any Pokémon that has been in a Sun or Moon game cannot be transferred to a 6th generation game (Omega Ruby, Alpha Sapphire, X or Y) **even if it is the game it originally came from**

It's unfortunate but avoids a lot of potential compatibility problems.

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/292555/185937) to a similar question has the official picture detailing Pokébank capabilities for all the versions starting with the DS games. You should have a look if ever you wish to buy an older game.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible so long as it has no new data, meaning that as long as it hasn't got any moves, ribbons or any other marking not possible in X/Y/or/as it is entirely possible to re-use it in gen 6.
I've even done so for breeding sake since x/y was much quicker at getting the tedious stages of IV breeding done to then finish off on gen 7 for tournament legality